# Unable to Normalize Tensor in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to normalize the tensor outputted by my network but am getting an error in doing so. The code is as follows:

```py
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model_load_path = r'path\to\saved\model\file'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_load_path))
model.eval()
output = model(input).to(device).view(-1, 1, 150, 150)
inv_normalize = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[-0.5/0.5], std=[1/0.5])
    ]
)
print(output.size())  # The size printed is torch.Size([1, 1, 150, 150])
output = inv_normalize(output)
```

I am getting an error in the following line:

```py
output = inv_normalize(output)
```

The error reads:

```py
TypeError: tensor is not a torch image.
```

My output is a single image, with a single channel, and height and width = 150

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply `transforms.Normalize` you have to convert the input to a tensor. For this you can use [`transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor).

```py
inv_normalize = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.toTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[-0.5/0.5], std=[1/0.5])
    ]
)
```

---

This tensor must consist of three dimensions (channels, height, width). Currently you have one dimension too much. Just remove the extra dimension in your `view` call:

```py
output = model(input).to(device).view(1, 150, 150)
```

Comment: My input is already a tensor. I still gave it a try and got the following error in transforms.ToTensor() `TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>`

Comment: Beside the requirement to be a tensor, the input to `transforms.Normalize` has to consist of three dimensions (x, y and color channel). Currently you have one dimension to much.